# "how could you know" vs "how can you know"

Tags: grammar, modal-verbs

Consider the following sentences:

- How **could** you know if you have cancer.
- How **can** you know if you have cancer.

Note that the sentences are **not interrogative**, but both of them are to be the **title of an article/news**.

What is the difference between the above two sentences (in meaning)?

Comment: If you want to write a title, simplify it: _How to know if you have cancer._ That would be my recommendation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know why OP says "the sentences are not interrogative". Obviously they *are*, regardless of whether the question mark is present or not.

> 1: *How **could** you know if you have cancer?*
>    2: *How **can** you know if you have cancer?*

OP has taken his two examples from *titles of articles*, in which context there's no possibility of them having different meanings. They'll both be followed by text answering the "title" question by setting out possible ways to self-diagnose that you have cancer.

---

In *other* contexts it would be possible to distinguish different implications. For example, interpreting ***could*** as the past tense of ***can*** in #1 leads to...

> 1a: *How **was it possible** for you to know you have cancer?*  (perhaps implying disbelief or surprise)

...or one could see *could* there as equivalent to ***would***, indicating an "irrealis" context. Using *could/would* like that "distances" the speaker from his enquiry *("I don't **actually** think I've got cancer - but if I **did**, how could/would I find out for sure?")*